# Rails active_admin : How to restrict admin_user to change other admin_users' passwords?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I have the following on my active_admin, which is just a default for admin_user model. This allows all the admin_users to change all other admin_users' passwords. Does anybody know how I can restrict admin_users from changing passwords of others?

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do     
  index do                            
    column :email                     
    column :current_sign_in_at        
    column :last_sign_in_at           
    column :sign_in_count             
    default_actions                   
  end

  filter :email                       

  form do |f|                         
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do       
      f.input :email                  
      f.input :password               
      f.input :password_confirmation  
    end                               
    f.actions                         
  end                                 
end
```

Comment: Okay. So U want one active_admin users from changing the other admin passwords rite?

Comment: what I want is exactly that!

Comment: sorry, actually what I want is that any admin_users cannot edit any other admins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to go might be to remove the password and password_confirmation fields from this form and create a "change password" action or maybe even a "my account" page where you can change your password.

A third way might be to only show the password fields when you're editing "yourself", like so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do     
  index do                            
    column :email                     
    column :current_sign_in_at        
    column :last_sign_in_at           
    column :sign_in_count             
    default_actions                   
  end

  filter :email                       

  form do |f|                         
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do       
      f.input :email
      if(f.object == current_admin_user)
        f.input :password               
        f.input :password_confirmation
      end
    end                               
    f.actions                         
  end                                 
end
```

Untested, but it should work.

**Update**
If you want one specific user to be able to update all other users' passwords like you suggest in the comment to your question, you could consider this:

```
form do |f|                         
  f.inputs "Admin Details" do       
    f.input :email
    if(current_admin_user.is_super_admin?)
      f.input :password               
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
  end                               
  f.actions                         
end
```

The `is_super_admin?` could refer to a boolean value `is_super_admin` or could be a method in your model depending on a `role` field:

```
#  role                 :string(255)

class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  ROLES = ['normal', 'super']
  SUPER_ROLE = 'super'

  def is_super_admin?
    role == SUPER_ROLE
  end
end
```

**Update 2**
You will indeed also want to prevent users from altering the post parameters to change others' passwords. Again, there's **option 1**, doing it in the controller. I have only shallow knowledge of ActiveAdmin, so maybe there's a better way, but this should work:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  controller do
    def create
      params.delete(:password)
      params.delete(:password_confirmation)
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Another (more elegant) solution would be to make sure your AdminUsers' passwords can't be changed through mass assignment. That kind of logic would go into the model:

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :login, :name, :email # .. and everything else you need to be able to edit through a normal form, but NOT password and password_confirmation
end
```

Then you will probably want to create your own `change_password` method where individual users can change their passwords. In the controller action saving that form, you would then do something like this:

```
def submit_change_password
  @admin_user = current_admin_user
  @admin_user.password = params[:password]
  @admin_user.password_confirmation = params[:password_confirmation]
  if @admin_user.save
    ..
  else
    ..
  end
end
```

This way they will only be able to change their own passwords.

Comment: actually, I found out that its better that any admin_users cannot edit other admin_users. A third way works pretty well. However, i am guessing this is fine at view level but not at controller level in that other admin can edit others by directly post params? is there any way to avoid that security issue?

Comment: There also are millions of hybrid options in between. You could do the same check in the controller `(current_admin_user == @admin_user)` so that you can save your "own" form if you don't want to create a separate `change_password` method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. But You can give a try,

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do

  actions :all, :except => [:new]

  controller do
    def action_methods
      if current_admin_user.role?(AdminUser::ADMIN_ROLE)
        super
      else
        super - ['edit', 'destroy']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what should be defined for AdminUser::ADMIN_ROLE? The app returns error with uninitialized constant AdminUser::ADMIN_ROLE

Comment: You should probably define `ADMIN_ROLE = 'role_name_here'` in your AdminUser model. If the AdminUser's role is the same as the role defined here, it will evaluate to true and execute `super`, otherwise it will subtract the `edit` and `destroy` actions.

Comment: In Your Case may be u should completely avoid edit and destroy irrespective of roles. i.e `actions :all except: [:new, :edit, :destroy]` and remove the controller code, If U want admin to have rolls then u need to add roles in your models.

Comment: sorry, I found out that what I need is that any admin_users cannot edit other admin_users.